# Getting data from Apache

Tags: apache, server

I want to receive data from an apache server to a client. I just need to receive a string, not a file, but I am curious about a simple way to implement it.

I tried to implement it in php, but it got complicated and gave up.

Comment: Please see [ask] and edit your question with * what you have * what you need * what you tried * where it worked (or not).

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where you have stuck? Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.